# Android asynchronous AIDL

Tags: android, asynchronous, aidl

I have a main app and a remote service app that connects each other using AIDL.

I'm doing synchronous process successfully in remote service, but how can I do an asynchronous process?

My AIDL file is this:

```
import pack.addonlibrary.Action; /* parcelable */

interface IAddon {
    void onBind();
    void onUnbind();

    int getCallbacks();

    List<Action> onPageStarted(String url);
    List<Action> onPageFinished(String url);

    List<Action> onClicked(String url);

    List<Action> onUserConfirm(boolean cancelled);
    List<Action> onUserInput(String input, boolean cancelled);  

}
```

In my remote service, I want to this:

```
@Override
public List<Action> onClicked(String url) {   
  httpRequest() => onFinish() => showToastInClient(result)
  //shows toasts in main app
}
```

Comment: Implement separate AIDL for callbacks. Have this AIDL take callbacks as parameters, with the methods probably returning `void`. Have the client implement the `.Stub` classes for the callbacks and pass instances to the AIDL-exposed service interface. Have the service use those callbacks to send results back to the client on some background thread forked from the service's `.Stub` methods. See [this pair of sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/Callback) for a demonstration.

Comment: I was searching examples in your github but couldn't find anything, anyway, really thanks for explanation and link.

Comment: Hey, another question just because of my curiosity, can I pass activity object to service using AIDL? I was looking Boat Browser source code and they are passing webview and activity, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: "can I pass activity object to service using AIDL?" -- I don't see how. Neither will inherit from a `.Stub` generated from AIDL. While there is some amount of IPC going on with `Activity`, AFAIK `Activity` itself is not referenced across process boundaries.

Comment: I know that too, but here is a screen of their remote service implemention (if you are interested) : http://i.imgur.com/jzActA9.png

Comment: I think Harneev's answer should be accepted

Answer (score 3):

You can implement AIDL asynchronously, by creating a new AIDL (for callbacks) as :

```
import pack.addonlibrary.Action;

oneway interface IAddOnCallback {

    void handleOnClicked(List<Action> actionList);
}
```

And by changing `onClicked` method of `IAddon` aidl class from:

```
List<Action> onClicked(String url);
```

to:

```
void onClicked(IAddOnCallback callback, String url);
```

After connecting to service and while calling `onClicked` method you can implement the callback object and can send that object to connecting service. Callback Stub (client) can be implemented as :

```
 IAddOnCallback.Stub callback = new IAddOnCallback.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void handleOnClicked(List<Action> actionList) throws RemoteException {
        // here you can perform actions
        //shows toasts in main app
    }
};
```

This is how you can do tasks asynchronously. Hope it helps.