# How to use a AIDL Remotecallback to bind and unbind safely?

Tags: android-studio, mobile, aidl

```
    I am trying to create a client and server type of implementation. I have a background service which need to send data to client when ever a specific method is called using aidl. I am using aidl just because the client and service are in different process.

    And make changes at client side when ever a method is invoked.

    Can some one help me with this Explained  with examples.

    1. I am able to bind to service but  I am not able to unbind from the service even after calling unbind(Serverconnection) from the client side. 

    I am trying to use [this book][1] at page number 141 Callbacks with AIDL.


      [1]: https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Android/Android%20Programming_%20Pushing%20the%20Limits%20%5BHellman%202013-11-04%5D.pdf


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

//This is how I have implemented it from the provided comments on this questions.


//Server side code to send data through AIDL
// AIDL used to send message across process.

        private final IMyAidlInterface.Stub mBinder = new 
      IMyAidlInterface.Stub() {
        @Override
        public void registerCallback(final IMListener imlistener) throws 
        RemoteException {
            if (imlistener !=null) mCallbacks.register(imlistener);

        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterCallback(IMListener imlistener) throws 
        RemoteException {
            if (imlistener !=null) mCallbacks.unregister(imlistener);

        }
        };
```

// send string message through handler

```
   public void createHandler(){
            mHandler = new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
            };
        }
```

//Method invocked in a separate thread to send data through

```
        private void register() {
        subject.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<VehicleMessage>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onNext(VehicleMessage message) {
                                       streamHandler(message,0);
                                       try {

////////////////////////////////// sends data trhough aidl from a bluetooth data receiver thread./////////////////////////////////



             sendToRemote(message);
                                   } catch (Exception e) {
                                       Log.i("error", "" + e);
                                   }

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onError(Throwable e) {

                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onComplete() {

                               }
                           }
            );
           }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Client side or UI side ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
        public ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder 
            iBinder) {
                mService = IMyAidlInterface.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);

                try {
                    mService.registerCallback(imListener);

                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }

// when disconnected from the server

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
                mService = null;


               };

// this is called from a separate thread when ever data is found


          public void sendToRemote(VehicleMessage message) {
            final int N = service.mCallbacks.beginBroadcast();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                try {
                    service.mCallbacks.getBroadcastItem(i).Dataupdate(message);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            service.mCallbacks.finishBroadcast();

            }
```

////////////////////// Increase a values in acounter and reset it every second to find number of messages received for each second/////////////////////

//////Handler used here

```
         private Handler mhandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                messageCount++;
                if(rFlag==false){
                    timer.schedule(new speedoThread(),0,1000);
                    rFlag=true;
                }
               super.handleMessage(msg);}};
```

Comment: "Explain in a better way" isn't a very specific question. Which parts of the example there don't you understand? There are plenty of other examples of AIDL if you search for them.

Comment: @Rup if you found examples please provide me a source. for aidl call backs.

Comment: Here's [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) - search for 'mCallback'. Here's [an example I found by searching for 'aidl callback' on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363766/android-asynchronous-aidl/34134998#34134998), although it looks like the one from your book. Here's [six results on GitHub for 'aidl callback'](https://github.com/search?q=aidl+callback) - I'd guess at least one of them is a complete working project. I haven't searched very hard for these.

Comment: I am able to use your documentation @Rup it was really usefull.